# uncaught exception: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'value'

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html5-video, jquery-slider

I'm writing my own video player based on the tutorial [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/)

When I load the page, I'm getting the title error.

Here's the code that deals with the slider:

```
//create html structure
//main wrapper
var $video_wrap = $('<div></div>').addClass('logan-video-player').addClass(options.theme).addClass(options.childtheme);
//controls wraper
var $video_controls = $('<div class="logan-video-controls"><a class="logan-video-play" title="Play/Pause"></a><div class="logan-video-seek"></div><div class="logan-video-timer">00:00</div><div class="logan-volume-box"><div class="logan-volume-slider"></div><a class="logan-volume-button" title="Mute/Unmute"></a></div></div>');                     
$lVideo.wrap($video_wrap);
$lVideo.after($video_controls);

//get new elements
var $logan_video_seek = $('.logan-video-seek', $video_container);

var seeksliding;            
var createSeek = function() {
    if($lVideo.attr('readyState')) {
        var video_duration = $lVideo.attr('duration');
        $logan_video_seek.slider({
            value: 0,
            step: 0.01,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            max: video_duration,
            animate: true,                  
            slide: function(){                          
                seeksliding = true;
            },
            stop:function(e,ui){
                seeksliding = false;                        
                $lVideo.attr("currentTime",ui.value);
            }
        });
        $video_controls.show();                 
    } else {
        setTimeout(createSeek, 150);
    }
};

createSeek();

var gTimeFormat=function(seconds){
    var m=Math.floor(seconds/60)<10?"0"+Math.floor(seconds/60):Math.floor(seconds/60);
    var s=Math.floor(seconds-(m*60))<10?"0"+Math.floor(seconds-(m*60)):Math.floor(seconds-(m*60));
    return m+":"+s;
};

var seekUpdate = function() {
    var currenttime = $lVideo.attr('currentTime');
    if(!seeksliding) $logan_video_seek.slider('value', currenttime);
    $logan_video_timer.text(gTimeFormat(currenttime));                          
};

$lVideo.bind('timeupdate', seekUpdate);
```

I'm not much of a jquery buff and this is the first time I'm working on plugins, so I have no idea what to do about this. Can't find much on google either.

Thanks for your time

**EDIT**
I've been through the JQuery UI API specs for the slider widget and found that I was probably setting the slider value incorrectly:

```
$logan_video_seek.slider('value', currenttime) // see seekUpdate() function above
```

I've changed it to read as follows:

```
$logan_video_seek.slider('option', 'value', currenttime);
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the same error:

> uncaught exception: cannot call methods prior to initialization: attempted to call method 'option'

I can't find anything in the slider api docs to initialize the slider though. I was sure that would've been done in the `createSeek` function above?

Comment: Where is $lVideo is declared? And from where this code is executed?

Comment: @AndrewD. it's much earlier in the code. I fixed the issue by removing `(jQuery)` right before the very last ; in the plugin. Not sure what this was for or why it was breaking the code, but now the controls show up (video also plays nicely). Now though, I'm getting an error saying `Object [object Object] has no method 'lVideo'`

Comment: As you continuously get errors, you could paste full code somewhere like [jsfiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net/) for completteness, but [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)  will be more suitable then for them.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in `createSeek()` is trying to initialize slider without blocking further execution (you don't wait for success and continue regargdless of whether init occured or not), and then, when it comes to `seekUpdate` it's not yet ready, as `$lVideo.attr('readyState')` is probably false.

Try to move `$lVideo.bind('timeupdate', seekUpdate);` inside `createSeek` after or before `$video_controls.show();` invocation like that:

```js
function createSeek() {
  if ($lVideo.attr('readyState')) {
    var video_duration = $lVideo.attr('duration');
    $logan_video_seek.slider({
    ...
    });
    $lVideo.bind('timeupdate', seekUpdate); // <-- notice line here
    $video_controls.show();
  } else {
    setTimeout(createSeek, 150);
  }
};
```

PS: why don't you simply declare functions as usual like
 `function myEvilFn() { /* evil code */ }`?
When debugged, you will be able to see the name of function in stack frame, also you shouldn't care about order of them. If you like to hide them, put them inside another function or lambda). But using assignment (`var fn=function(){...}`) you just make the order of them unnecessarily important.